# How can I read return value from Async method in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, grpc

My `async` method is as below:

```
public async Task<List<object>> handleSummaryOfWallets()
{
    string token = giveMeToken("URL AND CREDS");

    Channel channel = new Channel("NANANANA GIROUD", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

    OMGadminAPI.OMGadminAPIClient client = new OMGadminAPI.OMGadminAPIClient(channel);

    var summaryBalancesParams = new OMGadminAPIGetCurrenciesSummariesParams();

    summaryBalancesParams.AdminAuthTokenSecret = token;
    List<object> summariesCurrenciesOMGadmin = new List<object>();

    using (var call = client.GetCurrenciesSummaries(summaryBalancesParams))
    {
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            OMGadminAPICurrencySummary currencySummary = call.ResponseStream.Current;
            summariesCurrenciesOMGadmin.Add(currencySummary);
            Console.WriteLine(summariesCurrenciesOMGadmin);
        }
        return summariesCurrenciesOMGadmin;
    }
}
```

As you can see, above `async` method returns list of objects. I call this method as below:

```
var listOfBalances = balances.handleSummaryOfWallets().Wait();
```

and it gives me error:

> Error CS0815: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

From the error, I understand that this is not correct way to call `async` method. But I need to read ready list of objects from `async` fetched data. Its request-response, no real stable stream. So I need to generate this list only once per request. I'm using *gRPC* framework for RPC calls.

Please help me fetch this data and make ready to use.

Comment: `var listOfBalances = await balances.handleSummaryOfWallets();` ... en error is self-explanatory `Task.Wait()` returns nothing (`void`) ... edit: of course method which use this code have to be `async`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait) method waits for the `Task` to complete execution. It returns `void`. That is the reason why the exception.

Now to overcome the exception and to read the return value, one way is as mentioned in other answer and the comments; `await` the call as below:

```
public async void TestAsync()
{
    var listOfBalances = await handleSummaryOfWallets();
}
```

Note that your calling method should also be `async` method now.

As you are calling `Wait` in your code, it looks that you want the result immediately; you have nothing else left to do that does not depend on result. In that case, you may choose to stop `async` chain by calling `Wait`. But you need to do some changes as below:

```
public void TestAsync()
{
    var task = handleSummaryOfWallets();//Just call the method which will return the Task<List<object>>.
    task.Wait();//Call Wait on the task. This will hold the execution until complete execution is done.
    var listOfBalances = task.Result;//Task is executed completely. Read the result.
}
```

Note that calling method is no longer `async`. Other explanation is given in code-comments.

Other short alternative to above code is as below:

```
public void TestAsync()
{
    var listOfBalances = handleSummaryOfWallets().Result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `await` while calling your method

```
var listOfBalances = await balances.handleSummaryOfWallets();
```

Comment: Since `handleSummaryOfWallets` is calling an I/O operation and `await`ing it's response, it's correct for it to be `async` and inappropriate to start up another CPU based task to run it.

Comment: Did you miss the code in the question? It is declaring the method as `public async Task<List<object>> handleSummaryOfWallets()`... Or are you suggesting the OP makes it not async?

Comment: @Chris ah, I didn't see await in the method. Thanks